# Enable fingerprint in Ubuntu 22.04 using hp elitebook-g4

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I am unable to enable fingerprint scanner in my HP Elite Book g4 al though it has a fingerprint scanner. When ever I use `lsusb` command, it shows that there is a fingerprint device. After that I installed the necessary software using `sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd` command. But when ever I try to enable it using `fprintd-enroll` command, it shows the error:

```
Impossible to enroll:
GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

Comment: Attach your lsusb output here